# Why is the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (2016) not certified?

Tags: 16.04, dell

Dell sells this with Ubuntu 16.04, but it is not certified according to the Ubuntu certification list.

What does this mean?  Does it work or not?

Comment: Maybe Dell has some proprietary code to make Ubuntu play well with the Intel Kaby Lake chip...

Comment: Who knows? Only Dell and/or Canonical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All previous editions of this laptop have been [certified](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?query=xps&category=Laptop&level=Any&vendors=Dell) and Dell has a [long](https://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Dell_to_offer_Ubuntu_Linux_on_some_computers) track-record of working closely together with canonical. So I would feel highly confident, that it will run quite smoothly.

Why it might not be certified (yet)? Sometimes the different timelines (release of the os and release of the newest model) don't quite fit together perfectly, so it can take a few months until the certification might be done. Nevertheless I would not hesitate to buy it.